# Why I have Field dataAreaId Access denied in a Query?

Tags: axapta, x++, query-builder, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a problem, I used in my init **Form** a little Query.
I used this code :

```
query q = new Query();
QueryBuildDataSource qbds;
QueryRun queryRun;
qbds.addRange(fieldNum(MyTable,dataAreaId)).value(SysQuery::valueUnlimited());
queryRun = new queryRun(q);
if (! queryRun.prompt())
{
     element.close();
}
MyTable_ds.query(queryRun.query());
```

When I insered a value in my **query prompt** I will have a error message :

> "Can not select the Company field."

I have in my **Design** and **dataSource** this field , but I can't use in a Query. 
All other fields I can use without problems.

It's possible to use this field in a query?

Thanks your time,

enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot include `DataAreaId` in your queries.

You can however use `addCompanyRange` method on your query:

```
q.addCompanyRange("dat");
```

Try this:

```
query q = new Query();
QueryBuildDataSource qbds;   
QueryRun queryRun;

qbds = q.addDataSource("MyTable");
//Build you query 

q.allowCrossCompany(true);
q.addCompanyRange("dat");

queryRun = new queryRun(q);
if (! queryRun.prompt())
{
    element.close();
}
MyTable_ds.query(queryRun.query());
```

Comment: Another example on MSDN, and note the use of qry2.allowCrossCompany( true ); in the example.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc518738.aspx

Comment: Thanks @MaximLazarev I understood the _Company_ use. Thankful.